# Sell Orders Reverted - Uniswap

Tags: web3js

I'm using node library with web3.js, big number, and ethereumjs-tx, and I can get the "buy" orders that use either solidity function ethToTokenSwapOutput or tokenToEthSwapOutput to work great. But I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with the "sell" orders - where you are selling a certain amount of eth or tokens and your inputs are the minimum tokens or min eth to receive in return.

this is one of the solidity functions I'm trying to solve for but always reverts;

```
function tokenToEthSwapInput(uint256 tokens_sold, uint256 min_eth, uint256 deadline) external returns (uint256  eth_bought);
```

this is the JS code i'm using (and the public key is already added to the exchange ERC20 contract as approved

```
//converts ETH to TOKEN
async function calcEthSell(inputAmt, address) {
    let outputReserve = await getERCBal(address); //token pool size of exchange - separate function in above code
    let inputReserve = await getEthBal(address); //eth pool size  of exchange - separate function from above code
    let numerator = inputAmt * outputReserve * 997;
    let denominator = (inputReserve * 1000) + (inputAmt * 997);
    let output = numerator / denominator;
    //output is amount of tokens bought using input Eth
    return output;
};


//sell a set amount of ETH to purchase unknown amount of ERC
async function sell_input_ETH_output_ERC(input) {
    const price = await calcEthSell(input, exchangeAddress);
    const soldEth = input * (10 ** 18);
    const minTokens = Math.round(price * (10 ** 18) * .98); //2% out of market as minimum
    console.log(soldEth);
    console.log(minTokens);
    let deadline = new Date(Date() + 300 * 60000) / 1000;
    const encodedEthABI = await exchangeContract.methods.ethToTokenSwapInput(BigNumber(minTokens), deadline).encodeABI();
    const transactionNonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress, "pending");
    const transactionObject = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(transactionNonce),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(90000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(3 * (10 ** 9)), //' gwei
        to: toAddress,
        from: fromAddress,
        data: encodedEthABI,
        value: web3.utils.toHex(soldEth)
    };
    const tx = new Tx(transactionObject, {'chain': 'mainnet'});
    tx.sign(privateKey);
    const serializedEthTx = tx.serialize();
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedEthTx.toString('hex')).on('transactionHash', console.log)
    .catch(console.log);
}

//sell .1 eth as example
sell_input_ETH_output_ERC(.1);
```

this always reverts back for some reason

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash we can inspect?

Comment: Hard to see without a transaction, but I'd suggest having a good look at your maths?  I'd try a test trade with `minTokens` set to 0x1 and see what happens.